# PHP stock market analyser app will only insert first line of historic data into database

Tags: php

***Heres basic connection:***

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

if (!$connect) {
    die('Could not connect to database!');
}
mysql_select_db('stockmarket', $connect);
?>
```

The main code reads each stock in tickerMaster.php which is:

YHOO (YAHOO)
F    (FORD)
NFLX (NETFLIX)
ADBE (ADOBE)
GE   (GE)

Then each stock is read and used to download each stock's history from yahoo finance in the main code of the app 
This is the Netflix(NFLX) file that gets created for example when the main code runs. The other 4 stocks get created the same with obviously different numbers.
This is the Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume, Adj Close:

2015-08-14,124.959999,125.00,123.00,123.389999,8631900,123.389999
2015-08-13,120.989998,125.730003,119.339996,123.730003,15221000,123.730003
2015-08-12,121.470001,122.449997,118.660004,120.510002,13822500,120.510002
2015-08-11,120.010002,123.760002,120.00,122.739998,11047600,122.739998
2015-08-10,126.089996,126.50,121.510002,123.029999,13370600,123.029999

The main code below will create a table for each stock properly. However will 
only insert the first row from up above into the table and not loop through and 
insert all the rows for each stock.

***MAIN CODE:***

```
<?php
    include('includes/connect.php');

    function createURL($ticker) {
        $currentMonth  = date("n");
        $currentMonth  = $currentMonth - 1;
        $currentDay    = date("j");
        $currentYear   = date("Y");

        return "http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/
        table.csv?s=$ticker&d=$currentMonth&e=$currentDay&f=$currentYear
        &g=d&a=7&b=10&c=2015&ignore=.csv";
           //Aug.  10   2015

    function getCVSFile($url, $outputFile) {
        $content = file_get_contents($url);       
        $content = str_replace(
             "Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume, Adj Close", 
             "", 
             $content
        ); //above string comes with stock data
        //downloaded from yahoo. I don't want
        $content = trim($content);               
        file_put_contents($outputFile, $content);
    }   

    function fileToDatabase($txtFile, $tableName) {
        $file = fopen($txtFile, "r");

        while (!feof($file)) {
            $line    = fgets($file);
            $pieces  = explode(",", $line);

            $date    = $pieces[0];
            $open    = $pieces[1];
            $high    = $pieces[2];
            $low     = $pieces[3];
            $close   = $pieces[4];
            $volume  = $pieces[5];
            $adj_clo = $pieces[6]; 

            $amount_change  = $close - $open;
            $percent_change = ($amount_change/$open) * 100;

            $sql     = "SELECT * FROM $tableName";
            $result  = mysql_query($sql);

            if (!$result) {
                $sql_2 = "CREATE TABLE $tableName (date DATE, PRIMARY KEY(date),    open FLOAT, high FLOAT, low FLOAT, close FLOAT, volume INT, amount_change FLOAT, percent_change FLOAT, adj_clo FLOAT)";

                mysql_query($sql_2);
            }
            $sql_3 = "INSERT INTO $tableName (date, open, high, low, close, volume, amount_change, percent_change, adj_clo) 
                          VALUES ({$date}, {$open}, {$high}, {$low}, {$close}, {$volume}, {$amount_change}, {$percent_change}, {$adj_clo} )";

            mysql_query($sql_3);
        } 
        fclose($file);
    }

function main() {
    $mainTickerFile = fopen("tickerMaster.txt", "r");
    while(!feof($mainTickerFile)) {
        $companyTicker = fgets($mainTickerFile);
        $companyTicker = trim($companyTicker);

        $fileURL = createURL($companyTicker);
        $companyTxtFile = "txtFiles/".$companyTicker."txt";
        getCVSFile($fileURL, $companyTxtFile);
        fileToDatabase($companyTxtFile, $companyTicker);
    }                                  
}

main();

?>
```

Any help much appreciated on why only the first row is only getting inserted into database.

Comment: Are the while loops iterating over all rows of your file?

Comment: As far as I know. I tested it out by echo $line in the begining of the

Comment: fileToDatabase function.

Comment: all the rows for each stock were there

Comment: $pieces  = explode(",", $line);
  foreach ($pieces as $p) {
   echo $p;
  }

Comment: I also did that and got all the rows outputted

Comment: Could you please check the results of `mysql_query` calls? If `mysql_query` return `false` please check the return value of `mysql_error` function. You can also `echo` your SQL statements and try to put them directly into phpMyAdmin to check, if the queries are valid.

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with the fieldname of column `date` because it's a word reserved by MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: mysql_error is returning Duplicate entry '0000-00-00' for key 'PRIMARY' for each

Comment: Ok, that's the answer for your question ;-)

Comment: which 0000-00-00 is what is getting inserted into DB. I tried changing date to dates but same results

Comment: You have set table field `date` as your `primary key` so it must be unique in your table. If you don't know, what a primary key is, please read some tutorials about `mysql` first.

Comment: Thx so much Mario! I took out date as my prime getting all the rows now.

Comment: I summarised the comments and added it as a answer. While writing the answer I thought about why there is a value like `0000-00-00`, because values for `date` should be like `2015-08-14`. Please check if the values of `date` column are correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is the summarized answer based on the comments above:

1) You have to check, if the `while loops` are iterating over all rows.

2) Check if there are any problems in your SQL queries. (Check the return values of `mysql_query` calls and check the return value of `mysql_error` function if `mysql_query(...)` returns `false.`

3) Check if [keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) `date` can be used as a fieldname in a mysql table.

4) Finally `mysql_error` told us that new datasets cannot be inserted because there are rows with duplicate values of `date` column (the primary key of the table). You check why `date` is `0000-00-00` or define another primary key, if the values of `date` are valid.